# Interpreting perfect participle

Tags: grammar

Look at the sentences below

1. Having travelled to Texas, I can say a few things about it.
2. Having lived with him for 5 years, I know him better. (D I still live with him?)

Does 'having travelled to Texas' mean that I have travelled many times and that I ***still travel*** to Texas whenever I get an opportunity. Or does it only always talks about the past and says nothing about what occurs in the present? I am having trouble interpreting the first example compared to the second sentence.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: All you know in 1 is that the speaker has been to Texas at least once. Everything you know in 2 about the speaker's living arrangements is confined to the past.

Comment: @deadrat Can't I interpret 2 I have lived with him for 5 years, hence I know him better? Or are you interpreting it like. I lived with him for 5 years, hence I know him better? Also does 'having been living with him for 5 years, I know him better ' say that I have been living with him for 5 years and I am still living with him?

Comment: The absolute construction *having lived with him* doesn't specify the time period. It's grammatical to say, "Having lived with him for 5 years in the '90s, I know him better.* The present perfect *I have lived with him* has a connection to the present (hence the name ***present** perfect*) so it means the last five years. It's not grammatical to say, "I have lived with him for 5 years in the '90s."

Comment: @deadrat How would I describe a situation in which I have been living with  him for the last five years?

Comment: You just did: *I have been living with him for five years.* Verbs that form predicates in independent clauses (like the one after the colon) are called *finite*, which means they carry tense. Participles (like the ones in the absolute constructions above) are called *nonfinite*, which means they carry other meanings like completion or progression. Of course, completion may imply past time, but we can also say, "Next spring, I will have lived him with for five years", and that's completion that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @deadrat look at this: 

Having lived in Dublin all my life, I'm not used to being stopped at checkpoints, harassed and searched, which I was subjected to in Palestine.

Having lived in Bangalore all my life but never having visited Coorg, I decided quite happily to tag along with a bunch of friends to stay at the Last Resort. We drove late night on a Friday from Bangalore to get the most of the place over the weekend.

Is the above sentences contradictory as all my life should include the present moment, but using perfect participle excludes that possibility. So confusing. Please help!

Comment: Perfect participles are nonfinite verbs, i.e., they don't really carry tense. They carry the sense of continuing action (from the *having*) that is complete (from the past participle, here *lived*). The actual time period of the action is given in the rest of the sentence. From *All of my life*, we can conclude that your residence in Dublin is the case right up to the present moment.  But you could also say, "Having lived in Dublin up to that point" and the time period would end at whatever past time is given by *that point*.

Comment: In case you care, the idiom is *to get the most **out** of* to mean enjoy to the highest level.